# Where in Test11 is causing the assertion error?

Tags: java, swing

I have to create a PhotoProcessingSys class. These are the methods I have to use in the class

- **Constructor** - Takes as parameters a customer's name (string), and customer's address (four string values representing street, city, state, and zip code). An Address object will be created and used to initialize an Address instance variable. To practice exceptions, make sure you catch the IllegalArgumentException while creating the Address object. If an invalid address is provided, just use the default address associated with the Address class. Notice you do not need to generate any error message in this case. There are other tasks associated with the constructor (e.g., initializing balance to 0) that you need to figure out as part of your project.
- **Default Constructor** - Uses "NONAME" for the customer's name and relies on the default address associated with the Address class.
- **toString** - Prints the customer's name, address, and balance. Each piece of information is printed on a line by itself using the messages "Customer Name: ", "Customer Address: ", "Balance: ". See the public tests for format information.
- **imageTransaction** - Takes an image's name (imageName), a task description string (task), a task options string (taskOptions), and a boolean value (graphicalMode). This method is responsible for processing image requests.

  - The method will first call PictureManager.graphicalModeOn() if graphicalMode is true and PictureManager.graphicalModeOff() otherwise.
  - Process the specified task. The tasks we can have are:

    1. **display** - Displays the picture associated with imageName.
    2. **clear** - Clears the screen of any pictures that have been displayed.
    3. **displaylast** - Displays the last picture that was displayed.
    4. **blackandwhite** - Displays a black and white version of imageName.
    5. **posterize** - Displays a posterized version of imageName.
    6. **blackandwhiteposterize** - Displays a version of imageName that is in black and white and posterized.
    7. **selectcolors** - The taskOptions includes the colors that will be selected. We will use r or R to select red, g or G for green, and b or B for blue. Notice that many instances can appear in the string and spaces can appear anywhere. Here some examples of strings: "rb", "rBrrrrG",
       "   r R     G  ". Once any character appears, that color will be selected.
    8. **Invalid option** - If one of the above options is not provided, the method will not do any processing.
  - **showMessageDialog message** - After one of the seven image processing options has been processed (or an invalid option has been provided) your program must display the message "Continue" using JOptionPage.showMessageDialog. **Only call JOptionPane.showMessageDialog if graphicalMode is true.**
  - **Return value** - The method will return a string that describes the task that took place. For all the seven image processing options the string to return is the string returned by the corresponding PictureManager method. If an invalid image processing option was provided, the method will return "Invalid photoProcessing option".
  - **Cost** - Each image processing transaction cost $1.00 except selectcolors which is worth $2.00. You must keep track of the balance associated with all the image processing requests.
  - **Transaction's log** - After each image processing transaction, you need to store the string (see return value above) in a StringBuffer. This string will be preceded by "Transaction #{NUMBER}" where {NUMBER} represents the transaction's number. Transaction numbers start at 1. Notice that an invalid transaction counts as a transaction.
- **getTransactions** - Returns a String (not StringBuffer) with the transactions.
- **getBalance** - Returns the balance.
- Feel free to add any private methods you understand are needed.

this is my code for the class

```
package sysutilities;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PhotoProcessingSys {

    private String customerName;
    private Address customerAddress;
    private double balance;
    private int transactionNumber;
    private StringBuffer transactionLog;
    private static int selectColorsCost = 2;

    public PhotoProcessingSys(String name, String street, String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        try {
            customerAddress = new Address(street, city, state, zipCode);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            customerAddress = new Address();
        }

        customerName = name;
        balance = 0.0;
        transactionNumber = 1;
        transactionLog = new StringBuffer();
    }

    public PhotoProcessingSys() {
        this("NONAME", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public Address getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Customer Name: " + customerName + "\n" + "Customer Address: " + customerAddress + "\n" + "Balance: "
                + balance;
    }

    public String imageTransaction(String imageName, String task, String taskOptions, boolean graphicalMode) {
        transactionNumber++;
        String transactionDescription = "Transaction #" + transactionNumber + ": ";
        if (graphicalMode) {
            PictureManager.graphicalModeOn();
        } else {
            PictureManager.graphicalModeOff();
        }

        String result = "";

        if (task.equalsIgnoreCase("display")) {
            result = PictureManager.displayPicture(imageName);
            balance += 1.0;
        } else if (task.equalsIgnoreCase("clear")) {
            result = PictureManager.clearScreen();
            balance += 1.0;
        } else if (task.equalsIgnoreCase("displaylast")) {
            result = PictureManager.displayLastPicture();
            balance += 1.0;
        } else if (task.equalsIgnoreCase("blackandwhite") || task.equalsIgnoreCase("posterize")
                || task.equalsIgnoreCase("blackandwhiteposterize")) {
            boolean isBlackAndWhite = task.equalsIgnoreCase("blackandwhite")
                    || task.equalsIgnoreCase("blackandwhiteposterize");
            boolean isPosterize = task.equalsIgnoreCase("posterize") || task.equalsIgnoreCase("blackandwhiteposterize");
            result = PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize(imageName, isBlackAndWhite, isPosterize);
            balance += 1.0;
        } else if (task.equalsIgnoreCase("selectcolors")) {
            boolean red = true;
            boolean green = true;
            boolean blue = false;
            if (taskOptions != null && taskOptions.length() >= 3) {
                red = taskOptions.charAt(0) == 't' || taskOptions.charAt(0) == 'T';
                green = taskOptions.charAt(1) == 't' || taskOptions.charAt(1) == 'T';
                blue = taskOptions.charAt(2) == 't' || taskOptions.charAt(2) == 'T';
            }
            result = PictureManager.displayPictureSelectRedGreenBlue(imageName, red, green, blue);
            balance += 2.0;
        } else {
            result = "Invalid photoProcessing option";
        }

        transactionLog.append(transactionDescription).append(result).append("\n");

        if (graphicalMode) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Continue");
        }

        return result;
    }

    public String getTransactions() {
        return transactionLog.toString();

    }
        
    
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;

    }
```

this is the PictureManager class associated with the PhotoProcessingSys class

```
package sysutilities;

import javax.swing.*;
import cmsc131PictureLib.*;

public class PictureManager {
    private static boolean GRAPHICAL_MODE = true;

    public static void graphicalModeOff() {
        GRAPHICAL_MODE = false;
    }

    public static void graphicalModeOn() {
        GRAPHICAL_MODE = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        graphicDemo();
        nonGraphicDemo();
    }

    public static void graphicDemo() {
        PictureManager.displayPicture("testudo.jpg");
        PictureManager.displayPicture("http://www.cs.umd.edu/~nelson/classes/resources/cmsc131/imagesForProjects/logo.png");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press OK to clear screen");
        PictureManager.clearScreen();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press OK to display last picture");
        PictureManager.displayLastPicture();
        PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", true, false);
        PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", true, true);
        PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", false, false);
        PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", false, true);
        PictureManager.displayPictureSelectRedGreenBlue("testudo.jpg", true, false, false);
    }

    public static void nonGraphicDemo() {
        StringBuffer activity = new StringBuffer();
        PictureManager.graphicalModeOff();

        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPicture("testudo.jpg"));
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPicture("http://www.cs.umd.edu/sites/all/themes/cs/logo.png"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press OK to clear screen");
        PictureManager.clearScreen();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press OK to display last picture");
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayLastPicture());
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", true, false));
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", true, true));
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", false, false));
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize("testudo.jpg", false, true));
        activity.append(PictureManager.displayPictureSelectRedGreenBlue("testudo.jpg", true, false, false));

        System.out.println(activity);
    }

    public static String displayPicture(String name) {
        if (GRAPHICAL_MODE) {
            PictureUtil.show(new Image(name));
        }

        return "Display " + name + "\n";
    }

    public static String clearScreen() {
        if (GRAPHICAL_MODE) {
            PictureUtil.clearScreen();
        }

        return "clearScreen\n";
    }

    public static String displayLastPicture() {
        if (GRAPHICAL_MODE) {
            PictureUtil.show(PictureUtil.getLastPicDisplayed());
        }

        return "displayLastPicture\n";
    }

    public static String displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize(String name, boolean blackAndWhite, boolean posterize) {
        if (GRAPHICAL_MODE) {
            Picture result = new Image(name);
            if (blackAndWhite) {
                result = new BlackAndWhite(result);
            }
            if (posterize) {
                result = new Posterize(result);
            }
            PictureUtil.show(result);
        }

        return "displayPictureBlackWhitePosterize: " + name + ", " + blackAndWhite + posterize + "\n";
    }

    public static String displayPictureSelectRedGreenBlue(String name, boolean red, boolean green, boolean blue) {
        if (GRAPHICAL_MODE) {
            PictureUtil.show(new SelectComponents(new Image(name), red, green, blue));
        }
        
        return "displayPictureSelectRedGreenBlue: " + name + ", " + red + green + blue + "\n";
    }

    
    }
```

This is the PublicTest Provided

```
@Test
    public void test11() {
        /* getTransactions */
        String answer = "";
        
        PhotoProcessingSys photoProcessingSys = new PhotoProcessingSys("John", "8134 Java St.", "Silver Spring", "VA", "21567");
        answer += photoProcessingSys.imageTransaction(null, "clear", null, GRAPHICAL_MODE_FLAG);
        answer += photoProcessingSys.imageTransaction("umcp1.jpg", "display", null, GRAPHICAL_MODE_FLAG);
        answer += photoProcessingSys.imageTransaction("umcp1.jpg", "selectcolors", "rG", GRAPHICAL_MODE_FLAG);
        answer += photoProcessingSys.getTransactions();
        
        answer += TESTS_TAG;
        assertTrue(TestsSupport.isCorrect("pubTest11.txt", answer));
    }
}
```

The reason why I only provided the code for Test11 of the PublicTest is because that is the only one I'm failing with an assertion error. Can someone help create a test case to see the result printed or let me know where in my code is the problem.

Comment: We can't answer this.  The assertion is failing because `TestsSupport.isCorrect` is returning `false`.  That is a method provided by your teacher.  We don't *know* what it does.  (Though I can guess.)  To fix this, you first need to find out what it does (e.g. look at its source code or specification) ... then work out why it returns `false`.

Comment: My guess is that it (the `isCorrect` method) is comparing the `answer` string against the content of a file.  So you would need to look at the value in `answer` and in the file ... and work out where / why they are different.  *That* will most likely give you a clue as to what your actual error is.

Comment: In order to help you debug your code, I need to reproduce your problem - which I can't do based on the code in your question - and I very much doubt that anyone will be able to help you just by looking at the code that you did post. I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Also, in order to reproduce your problem, do I have to use the same images as you, or can I use any image?

Comment: Abra is correct ... but I doubt that a minrep is actually feasible in this case.  There is most likely too much code for an SO question. That is the basis for my suggested approach which is that you need to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: But if you are simply trying to create a test case ... you could easily modify the one you have there to add a `System.out.println` (or whatever) to print out `answer`.  Or run the existing test in a debugger, set a breakpoint at the appropriate place, single step it, and look at the relevant variables.  (Once again this is advice on how >you< can find the solution!!)

Comment: @StephenC Thank you I found the problem. I created the test case and found that the results weren't similar because I forgot to add one word. Thank you once again!